# It it possible to define attributes of a group in a netCDF4 file using python?

Tags: python, netcdf

I am using [`netcdf4-python`](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#netCDF4.Dataset.createGroup) to access and write `netCDF` files. Now since `netCDF4`, adding [`groups`](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#netCDF4.Group) to files is possible. So I am going to create groups and add attributes to that group. Is it possible to add attributes like a *long_name* or a *group description* to the group ?

I tried it by using the same approach like for variables, but no success:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset

ds = Dataset(path, 'w', format="NETCDF4") 

group1 = ds.createGroup("Group 1")
group1.long_name = "Group description"
```

Anyone an idea ?

Comment: ``stats_output.createGroup()`` was intended to be ``ds.createGroup()``, right?

Comment: oh yes thats a mistake thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine, you just forgot a `ds.close()` in the end.

Comment: did you test this with netCDF4 format ? For me it doestn work

Comment: Yes, I just copied your example. What does ``ncdump -h <path>`` print?